# Get select and input values on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select, input, and a button, i want when i click on the button to add the option value and the input value in an alert, i managed to do that but on change and only with the select, how can i get the select and input value onclick in the same alert? here is my code:

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  alert( this.value );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
<input type="text" value="Input">
<button type="button">Get value</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following:

```
$('#myButton').on('click', function() {
  var text = $('#myInput').val() + ' ' + $('#mySelect').val();
  alert(text);
})

<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>

<input id="myInput" type="text" value="Input">
<button id="myButton" type="button">Get value</button>
```

Instead of `id` binding you may use some another way, for example `$('button')`, `$('select')` and `$('input')`. Instead of selected option `value` attribute you may show selected option text: `$('#mySelect option:selected').text()`.

Comment: @jessica I updated the answer. You see, it's the same story: appropriate jquery-selector  and `.val()`.

Comment: Since we've changed the title and fixed the issue, let me do a little upvote for you...

Answer (score 1):

`this` in your event function isn't a jquery object, it's a dom object. Address it as `$(this)` that is JQuery object.

Infact

- `this.value` - the way of accessing in JS, no jQuery
- `$(this).val()` - this is the way of accessing value in jQuery

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  alert( $(this).val() );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>

<button type="button">Get value</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select').on('change', function(e) {
  alert($(e.target).val());
})
```

this will work on all selects, but will alert only current selected value.
**e** is event

Answer (score 0):

When you **click the button** the alert targetting the select option selected and show the value.

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  console.log( $(this).val() );
})

$('button[type="button"]').on('click', function(){
    alert($('select').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>

<button type="button">Get value</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code will run when you click the button. It will popup the message with the selected option. If you want showcase all the values in the data then remove the option:selected.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('button').click(function() { 
      alert($('select option:selected').text());
  });
});


</script>
<select>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>

<button type="button">Get value</button>
```

Comment: $('select').on('change', function() {
  alert( this.value +' - ' + $('input').val());
})

Comment: $(document).ready(function() { 
  $('button').click(function() { 
      alert($('select option:selected').text() + ' - ' + $('input').val());
  });
});

Answer (score 0):

It's better to call a function onClick and pass the target element Id to get the value.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select id="select">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>

<button type="button" onclick="getValue('select')">Get value</button>

<script>
function getValue(e) {
    var targetElement = document.getElementById(e);
    var alertValue = targetElement .options[targetElement .selectedIndex].text;
    alert(alertValue);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```